# Is there a direct sum decomposition of the tensor product of two representations of two group elements?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I know that I can decompose $\rho_a(g) \otimes \rho_b(g)$ into $U^\dagger \left[ \rho_c(g) \oplus \rho_d(g) \right] U$.  Is there a similar way to decompose $\rho_a(g_1) \otimes \rho_b(g_2)$ into $U^\dagger \left[ \rho_c(g_1) \oplus \rho_d(g_2) \right] U$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be the group in question.  In the first case, you are decomposing  the $G$-representation $\rho_a \otimes \rho_b$ into $G$-representations.  In the second case, $\rho_a(g_1) \otimes \rho_b(g_2)$ is actually a value of the $(G \times G)$-representation $\rho_a \otimes \rho_b$, so it will decompose into $(G \times G)$-representations $\rho_{e}((g_1,g_2)) \oplus \rho_f((g_1,g_2))$.